# Create OpenERP model interaction with HR_Payroll

Tags: odoo

I am new to `OpenERP 7` I was create my own model to store student data , Now I need to deal with the objects in `OpenERP 7` for example how to view Basic salary for Employee in My New Model

or in other words I want from my model to access data for other model (for example get total leaves for employee)
Can I get simple example about this  ? or if there is tutorial or simple book
Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use inheritance concept in OpenERP to achieve your requirements. You can inherit object as well as views, methods as per your need. You need to use _inherit attribute to inherit object and for view, you need to use inherit_id to override the existing view. You can also define relation ship (many2one/one2many/many2many) between your objects to access data of other model.

You can refer this links:

```
http://doc.openerp.com/trunk/developers/server/
http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/index.html#book-develop-link
```

Also, you will find such many examples in official addons code.

Comment: I want to enter this field .. if you can explain by example step by step or if there is tutorial for that I am searching but there is less documents and examples for this topic , Thank you in advance